# How to pass data between two controllers in which one controller is abadressbook fetched in uitableviw

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, abaddressbook

I created an `ABAddressBook` on a `UITableView`. Now, I need to pass the `firstname`, `last name`, etc. to next viewcontroller.

I have to pass data using nsobject class ... in this project i have made Person class which has string properties of name,lastname,number,email.

The code for address book is:

```
ABRecordRef source = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBook);
allPeople = (__bridge NSMutableArray *)(ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook, source, kABPersonFirstNameProperty));
NSInteger numberOfPeople = [allPeople count];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < numberOfPeople; i++) {
    personContact = [[Person alloc]init];

    person = (__bridge ABRecordRef)allPeople[i];

    NSString *firstName = (__bridge NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    NSString *lastName  = CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty));
    if (firstName == nil ) {
        firstName = @"";
    }
    if (lastName == nil)
    {
        lastName = @"";
    }

    NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",firstName,lastName];

    personContact.firstName = firstName;
    personContact.lastName = lastName;
    personContact.fullName = fullName;

//For adding multiple contacts:



ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue((person), kABPersonPhoneProperty);

    CFIndex numberOfPhoneNumbers = ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers);
    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < numberOfPhoneNumbers; i++) {
        NSString *phoneNumber = CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, i));

        if ([phoneNumber isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            phoneNumber = @"Not Available";
        }

        NSCharacterSet *trim = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"#();$&-+"];
        phoneNumber = [[phoneNumber componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: trim] componentsJoinedByString: @""];
        phoneNumber= [phoneNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
        phoneNumber=[phoneNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"" withString:@""];

        personContact.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;

//Emails

        ABMutableMultiValueRef eMail  = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
        if(ABMultiValueGetCount(eMail) > 0)
        {
            email =CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(eMail, 0));
        }
        else
        {
            email =  @"";
        }
        personContact.email = email;
    }

//Photos

    CFDataRef imgData = ABPersonCopyImageData(person);
    NSData *imageData = (__bridge NSData *)(imgData);

    phoneImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    if (phoneImage == nil) {
        phoneImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"userEdit"];
    }
    CGSize destinationSize = CGSizeMake(70, 70);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(destinationSize);
    [phoneImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, destinationSize.width, destinationSize.height)];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    if (imgData != NULL)
    {
        CFRelease(imgData);
    }
    personContact.photos = (NSString *)newImage;

    [contactsData addObject:personContact];
    [contactstableView reloadData];

}
}


And the code for cellforrowatIndex path is as follows:- 
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"CellID";
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier]; 
if (cell==nil)
{

   cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
   cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:238.0/255.0 green:238.0/255.0 blue:239.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
 }


if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    personContact = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}
else {
    personContact = [contactsData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}
if (contactsData.count > 0)
{
    cell.textLabel.text = personContact.fullName;

    cell.imageView.image = personContact.photos;
    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 35;
    cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

  }
```

On `didselect` row, I want to pass all the contact details to next controller. Please help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: i need same implementation of cellForRowAtIndexPAth like this example    http://www.appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7/

Answer (score 1):

If you have to pass it from ABAddressBook to ViewController use delegate methods

If you have to pass it to ABAddressBook you can Pass ABPerson or Associative properties

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(actionSheet, @"selectedUserJidStr", selectedUserJidStr, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
```

Comment: i have fetched data in my uitableview as show above , now i need to pass data of cell @ankit

Comment: personContact = [contactsData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: i need same implementation of cellForRowAtIndexPAth like this example appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7  @ankit

Comment: In Next view controller create a property and from TableViewController populate the property with object at selected indexpath

Comment: I have done that but the textfields in the next fields are not getting populated

Comment: What is the class of object you are trying to pass and also share the code where you are passing it and property where you declared it

Comment: i have shared it below @ankit and for class i use nsobject class whose name is Person and  properties in it is firstName,lastName,phoneNumber ..

Comment: Please do a basic debugging

Comment: sorry did`nt get you @ankit

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will display view on cell select, which you can do using following delegate method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueName" sender:indexPath];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueName"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = sender;
        ViewControllerName *objectOfViewControllerName = segue.destinationViewController;
        objectOfViewControllerName.personContact = [contactsData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this in cellforrowAtIndexPath

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
    AddGuestVC *add = [[AddGuestVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"AddGuestVC" bundle:nil];

    add.personContact = [contactsData objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];

    add.delegate = self;
   add.personContact = personContact;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:add animated:YES];
}
}
```

and for populating textfield i use :

```
   firstname.text = self.personContact.firstName;
```